# Not Able to Upload Files to Server

Tags: ftp

Hi I am trying to simply copy files from one location of my server to another via FTP. However when I try to copy my saved files from first location to my second location, the processes keep failing in Filezilla. Below is the history:

```
Status: Starting upload of /home/zachary/Downloads/ServerInfo/duh/server_info/LDC_plugins/ach-bulletin/tom/jquery.markitup.pack.js
Command:    PASV
Response:   550 jquery.markitup.js: Permission denied
Error:  Critical error
```

Any help on figuring this would would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error specifically states a permissions error so if you can give us more details it might help. Make sure the transfer file type is either auto detect or ascii since it is a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give more info. What is FTP Server software are you using, what OS is the server running on. Are you copying the files from one folder to another on the same serer, or from a client machine to the server, etc...

Comment: Sorry. I am using Filezilla FTP software, the OS is Linux. I am able to save files from the main domain folders, but when I try to move them to a subdomain folder I keep getting this perms error. The folder is set to 755

Comment: He wanted to know if the server you are uploading files to is under your administration, or if it is owned by someone else.  If it is yours, what server software (OS, and FTP daemon) is it running?

Comment: That is correct. If you are running the FTP Daemon, then just make sure the account you are logging on with has the correct permissions. If the FTP server is administered by someone else you should contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Simple checklist of things to check when having FTP issues: ownership, permissions, make sure they are not chattr'ed, make sure the passive FTP ports are open in the FTP config and the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the permissions on the server.  you need to ensure that your user account you are logged in with has at least 755 permissions on that particular folder.